# How to add zeros from left side to reight side for a given number

Tags: postgresql

can you please convert the below left hand side zeros to right hand.
example:

```
Number        output
0012345        1234500
00008794       87940000
```

Please help me which function will give the above result.

Comment: You've multiplied the first number by 100, and the second number by 10000.  Can you explain the logic here?

Comment: the logic is how many zero is there in right hand side in a given number that many zeros added to left hand side

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that `Number` is of type `text`, otherwise it wouldin't retain the leading zeros. Then, the following should do it:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(Number,'^(0*)([0-9]*)','\2\1') AS output;
```

If want the `output` to be an integer, you can simply typecast it:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(Number,'^(0*)([0-9]*)','\2\1')::integer AS output;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do this is python.

eg:

```
 a = "0012345"
 str(int(a)) + (len(a) - len(str(int(a))))*"0"
```

Comment: I think the OP wants a SQL solution.

Comment: OP didn't explicitly mention it thought! Just another example maybe :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another option:

```
SELECT CAST(Number AS int) * 10 ^ (LENGTH(Number) - LENGTH(REPLACE(Number, '0', '')))
FROM yourTabl
```

**Explanation:**

The `CAST` would remove any leading zeroes leaving behind an integer, e.g. `12345`.  This number is then multiplied by ten raised to the number of zeroes which padded the original text the left.